# How to replace an exact word in a text file

Tags: c

When I open the temporary file I see that the word is replaced. The string in the main file is printed in the temporary file without any spaces.

How can I fix this?

```
while (!feof(ptr2))
{
    strcpy(string, "\0");
    fscanf(ptr2, "%s", string);
    if (!strcmp(string, word)) // If match found
        num++;

    if (strstr(string, word))
    {
        r2 = string;
        while (r1 = strstr(r2, word))
        {
            while (r2 != r1)
            {
                fputc(*r2, temp);
                r2++;
            }
            r1 = r1 + strlen(word);
            fprintf(temp, "%s", word1);
            r2 = r1;
        }
        while (*r2 != '\0') {
            fputc(*r2, temp);
            r2++;
        }
    }
    else {
        fputs(string, temp);
    }
```

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: `"%s"` skips all white space; you'll have to output white space when you want it to see it in the output.  You need to think about when you want blanks and when you want newlines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Is there a shorter version? (oo)

Comment: @Nguaial : Is there a shorter version of what?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler- The link you sent was a really a long read.  But thanks for the link.  All this time, I used while(!feof(file)){}, I didn't get any ill effects in my application. But I realize how important to know the difference.

Comment: Should the second `if` clause be inside the first `if` clause? That is what the original indentation suggested (I have fixed the indentation according to how the compiler sees it). If that is the case, where was the else part intended to belong to?

Comment: @nguai: the shorter version of the link is the title — don't use `while (!feof(fp))`.